# General German-English dictionary with Austrian/Swiss words

Tags: dictionary

What general German-English dictionary does the best job of covering Austrian and Swiss terms?

**Edit.** I was talking about words and expressions that appear in texts or oral passages in the Austrian and Swiss varieties of Standard German. If possible, this might also include certain dialect words, when these are used in the middle of a standard German sentence with some frequency and would be assumed known to readers/listeners nationwide (not just locally).

Also, I had a paper dictionary in mind, but any dictionary of equivalent editorial quality will do. I want a dictionary that I can use for German in general, not one that is specialized in Austrian and Swiss terms.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for. Are you looking for online translators or real dictionaries? Also by Austrian and Swiss words do you mean Austrina/Swiss Standard German or dialects spoken in those countries? (There is a huge difference: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/was-ist-mit-%C3%96sterreichisch-gemeint-in-sprachlicher-hinsicht/).

Comment: I don't know if I understand this right: You are looking for a dictionary where e.g. "potato" is translated to "Kartoffel" und "Erdapfel" (second one being not dialect, but a word used in Austria)?

Answer (score 2):

By "Swiss and Austrian terms" I understand the standard German vocabulary used in writing in Switzerland or Austria differing from the vocabulary used in Germany (which isn't uniform there, neither).

Let's take the English *cabbage* as an example. There are many species, but the main distinction is between the smooth-leaved, firm-headed green cabbage (Kohl in northern Germany, Kraut in Austria, Weisskabis in Switzerland) and the crinkle-leaved white or savoy cabbage (Weißkohl or Wirsing in n. Germany, Kohl in Austria, Kabis in Switzerland). Those allocations are far from precise but they give a general idea of what a dictionary would have to accomplish if it tried to cover all English and German terms for these kinds of plants.

> I happen to have only the Langenscheidt Handwörterbuch at hand where
>   *cabbage* is translated as *Kohl(pflanze)* and *Kohlkopf*, and *savoy* as *Wirsing(kohl)*. *Kohl*, on the other hand, is translated as
>   *cabbage* with a reference to *Kraut*, only to refer this one to *Kohl* and *cabbage* again. Here, the range of local terms is narrowed down to what is probably common in a big part of nothern Germany. This
>   is also a question of space; the more comprehensive the dictionary,
>   naturally, the more terms can be included that are specific and
>   regional.
>
> This is the big advantage of online dictionaries; they never lack space. If you take a look
>   at the *cabbage* entry in [www.dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=cabbage), you will find *Kohl*,
>   *Kraut*, *Kabis*, *Kappes* and *Kappus* there. Of course this is also due to the fact that the users themselves contribute to that
>   dictionary. Whereas reliability is an issue sometimes, those online community systems constantly try to improve their quality.

As far as tangible items are concerned, I think you might be best off with a German pictorial dictionary which includes regional terms from Austria and Switzerland. I don't know if such a dictionary exists but it could be worth while investigating.

If you're looking for a dictionary providing translations from English to Swiss or Austrian dialects, I think you're out of luck; there are a lot of different dialects out there, differing in both vocabulary and pronunciation, and what is more, there is no spelling standard which could be applied to such a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO one of the best online dicts is [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org)
And it seems to also fulfill your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Nachdem du dich für Unterschiede zwischen den verschiedenen Varietäten der deutschen Sprache interessierst, nehme ich an, dass deine Deutschkenntnisse gut genug sind, um eine Antwort in deutscher Sprache zu verstehen. Meine Muttersprache ist nämlich österreichisches Deutsch, und darin kann ich mich nun mal besser ausdrücken als in Englisch.

Wenn ich deine Frage richtig verstanden habe, suchst du ein Englisch-Deutsch-Wörterbuch, in dem bei den deutschen Wörtern angegeben ist, zu welcher Varietät sie gehören. Ich fürchte, so ein Wörterbuch gibt es nicht.

Es gibt nämlich ein Problem, das ich am Beispiel Deutschland-Österreich erläutern will:

Viele Wörter, die zum Wortschatz des Österreichischen Deutsch gehören, werden auch im Süden Deutschlands (hauptsächlich in Bayern) verwendet, aber das trifft eben nicht auf alle Wörter zu. Vor allem die Wörter der österreichischen Amts-Sprache (Lokalaugenschein, Parteienverkehr, Gleichschrift, usw.) sind tatsächlich nur in Österreich in Gebrauch, während Ausdrücke aus der Küchensprache (Erdäpfel, Eierschwammerl, Kren) auch in weiten Teilen Deutschlands verwendet werden, oder zumindest verstanden werden.

Aber es gibt nicht nur schwer zu definierende Unterschiede von Land zu Land, sondern auch innerhalb eines Landes. Der englische *butcher* ist im Osten Österreichs der *Fleischhauer*, im Westen hingegen der *Metzger*, und in Deutschland sind je nach Region die Begriffe *Metzger* und *Fleischer* in Verwendung.

Bei einigen Wörtern hingegen unterscheidet sich nur die Aussprache. Beim Wort »Kaffee« wird beispielsweise in weiten Teilen Deutschland die erste Silbe stark betont, und die zweite hingegen gar nicht (also wie »Affe« mit einem vorangestellten k). In Österreich ist es genau umgekehrt, zudem wird das e am Ende stark gedehnt (Kaf*eeee*).

Das von dir gewünschte Wörterbuch müsste also in letzter Konsequenz für jedes einzelne deutsche Wort dessen Verbreitungsgebiet angeben. Das wäre zwar möglich, würde das Wörterbuch aber sehr stark aufblähen. Und der Verlag, der sich diese Arbeit antut, würde dann auch entsprechende Werke für Französisch-Deutsch oder Japanisch-Deutsch herausbringen wollen, aber kaum jemand würde die sehr dicken Wälzer dann kaufen, wenn es von anderen Verlagen viel dünnere Wörterbücher mit genau dem Inhalt gibt, für den sich ein Wörterbuch-Käufer üblicherweise interessiert.

Aber es gibt etwas anderes, das deinem Wunsch wenigstens Nahe kommt. Es ist das ...

### Variantenwörterbuch des Deutschen

Dieses Buch enthält genau jene deutschen Wörter, die nicht im gesamten Deutschen Sprachraum verwendet werden, also Wörter, die jeweils nur in einem Teil dieses Gebiets gesprochen werden.

Die Wörter in diesem Wörterbuch gehören fast alle einer der drei »genormten« Standard-Varietäten an, sind also keine Dialekt-Wörter. Es gibt aber Ausnahmen: Dialekt-Wörter, und Wörter der Umgangssprache stehen dann im Variantenwörterbuch, wenn sie häufig in Standard-Texten (also z.B. in Zeitungsartikeln) vorkommen.

Im Fokus stehen die Varietäten der Deutschen Sprache wie sie in Europa gesprochen wird (nämlich in Deutschland, Österreich, Schweiz, Belgien, Luxemburg, Liechtenstein und Italien). Eine Erweiterung um das in Afrika gesprochene Namibia-Deutsch ist in Arbeit. Ob später auch einmal auch die amerikanischen Varitäten [Texas-Deutsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texasdeutsch) oder [Pennsilfaanisch Deitsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania_Dutch_(Sprache)) hinzukommen weis ich nicht, ich halte es aber für eher unwahrscheinlich, weil umstritten ist, ob es sich hier noch um Varietäten oder schon um eigenständige Sprachen handelt. Auch Varietäten anderer deutscher Sprachinseln (z.B. in Polen, Russland, Brasilien und Australien) wird man vermutlich weiterhin nicht in diesem Buch finden.

Bei jedem Wort in diesem Wörterbuch steht nicht nur sein Verbreitungsgebiet, sondern es gibt auch Verweise auf Synonyme in anderen Gebieten.

zwei Beispiele:

**deppert**
wird als Grenzfall eines Standardwortes beschrieben das in Österreich und dem Südosten Deutschlands in Gebrauch ist, und im übrigen Deutschland durch *dämlich*, *dusselig* und *bescheuert*, sowie im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum durch *dumm* und *blöd* ersetzt werden kann

**Knüller**
Hier wird angegeben, dass dieses Wort in Deutschland (ohne dem Südosten) üblich ist, in den übrigen Regionen aber selten verwendet wird, und allgemein durch *Sensation* ersetzt werden kann.

Mehr dazu hier:

[Beschreibung es Variantenwörterbuchs bei Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variantenw%C3%B6rterbuch_des_Deutschen)
[Variantenwörterbuch bei Google Books](http://books.google.at/books/about/Variantenw%C3%B6rterbuch_des_Deutschen.html?id=EJoVyz8_J14C&redir_esc=y)
[Variantenwörterbuch bei Amazon](http://www.amazon.de/Variantenw%C3%B6rterbuch-Deutschen-Standardsprache-Oesterreich-Liechtenstein/dp/3110165740)

Comment: Interessant. Wenn man aber kein wissenschaftliches Interesse hat, genügt dann auch der Duden? Wie häufig sind österreichische Wörter, die er nicht enthält?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Ich habe stichprobenartig nach einigen Austriazismen gesucht, und tatsächlich die meisten, aber nicht alle im Duden gefunden. Es scheint also einige österreichische Wörter zu geben, die nicht im Duden stehen. Nachgesehen habe ich in der 23. Auflage des Duden aus dem Jahr 2004. Gefunden habe ich: Hendl, Melanzani, Mezanin, Lokalaugenschein, deppert, Fisole, Sackerl, picken, das Koch, antauchen. Nicht gefunden habe ich: anzipfen, einzwicken, Waschmuschel, Hackler. Beim Spritzer und beim Pfiff fehlt im Duden bei beiden der Hinweis darauf, dass das in Österreich Getränke sind.

Comment: Danke, sehr hilfreich!

Answer (score -3):

Welcome Dave!

You will not find such a book. Be aware that German and Swiss are 2 different languages. Although they come from German , but differ significantly.

Here's a simple example:

**English:** House

**German:** Haus

**Austro:** Haus

**Swiss:** **Huus**

You need to understand that Austria has a huge dialect of the german language.

Comment: This is plain wrong. Plattdeutsch: Hus (or similar). Bavarian: Heisl or Hoam. Saxonian Häüs (slightly over-coloured). The differences inside German dialects are a lot larger than those between Swiss and the neighbouring Alemannian dialects. (Or those between Bavarian and Austrian/Vorarlbergian and Allgäuer.)

Comment: Indeed! I just want to make clear, that there is a difference and no dictionary will fit the needs.

Comment: Additionally, written Swiss will use the spelling 'Haus' like both written German and Austrian. See [a random article](http://www.nzz.ch/panorama/wegen-sturmwinden-stehen-bahnen-still-1.18513843) from the Neue Zürcher Zeitung.

Comment: Danke für die Hinweise Jan :) Das ist mir schon bewusst. Vor allem die öffentlichen Zeitungen drucken in Hochdeutsch ihre Ausgaben. Allerdings wollte ich nur klar stellen, dass es kein Wörterbuch gibt, welches English zu Deutsch, Österreichisch und Schweizerisch übersetzt. Dann müsste man schon direkt auf die Suche nach den Dialekten der einzelnen Sprache gehen.

Comment: Dann schreib das, und schreib nicht einen Schmarrn wie »das sind zwei unterschiedliche Sprachen«. Außerdem kann man die Frage auch anders verstehen: Ein D–E-Wörterbuch, das eine hohe Abdeckung an Helvetismen und Austriazismen enthält. Es ist oft schon hilfreich, wenn bei »cream« nicht nur »Sahne« sondern auch »Obers« steht, und umgekehrt sowohl »Sahne« als auch »Obers« auf »cream« verweisen. Oder dass »abschlagen« in der Schweiz etwas anderes bedeutet als in Deutschland/Österreich. Ich gebe ja zu, dass die Frage schlecht gestellt ist, aber das macht deine Antwort nicht weniger falsch!